# Insert value in a column if value in another column contains a certain word/letter

Tags: r

I am essentially trying to create some code to detect if the values in a column contains "%". If so, make df$unit col to be %. if not so, do nothing.

I tried the below code but it returns % for all rows of values, even if they don't contain % inside.

How should I fix it?

```
if(stringr::str_detect(df$variable, "%")) {
        
        df$unit <- "%"
        
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `tidyverse` approach

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(unit = if_else(str_detect(variable,"%"),"%",unit))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
library(stringr)

df[str_detect(df$variable, "%"), 'unit'] <- "%"
```

This doesn't need any extra libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can use `replace` with `grepl`.

```
df <- transform(df,unit = replace(unit, grepl('%', variable, fixed = TRUE), '%'))
```

Or

```
df$unit[grepl('%', df$variable, fixed = TRUE)] <- '%'
```